# Creating the BuildDefinition in rally using C#

Tags: c#, rally, agile

I was trying to create a build definition. I tried as below one.
But i do think the code below doesn't create a buildDefinition. Like it asks for BuildDefinitionRef in the code "newBuild["BuildDefinition"] = ;" I am unable to know what exactly to put which reference.

```
     RallyRestApi RestApi = new RallyRestApi("_abcd","https://rally1.rallydev.com");

         String workspaceRef = "/workspace/27154845988";
        String projectRef = "/project/48152113168";

        DynamicJsonObject newBuild = new DynamicJsonObject();
        newBuild["Workspace"] = workspaceRef;
        newBuild["Duration"] = 0.75;
        newBuild["Message"] = "Master 4683 Success";
        //newBuild["CreationDate"] = "";
        newBuild["Status"] = "FAILURE";
        newBuild["Number"] = "4683";
        // newBuild["Uri"] = "http://jenkins-build:8080/hudson/view/master/job/master-deploy/4683/";
      // newBuild["BuildDefinition"] = ;
```

If any body has any idea of first how to create the BuildDefinition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BuildDefinition should be a createable type in WSAPI.  You just need to create that first, and then when you're creating your Build object just pass the ref of the created BuildDefinition:

```
newBuild["BuildDefinition"] = "/builddefinition/12345";
```